# Java socket timeout connection timeout by socket connect, but fine by UNIX ping tools

Tags: java, linux, unix, networking

I have 1 machine, which i pinged using below scripts

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

class SimplePing 
{
    static void connectAndPing(String host, int port, int loop, int pingLoop, int socketTimeout){
        if(loop>0){
            SocketAddress sAdress;
            Socket kkSocket;
            for(int i=0;i<loop;i++){
                sAdress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
                for(int j=0;j<pingLoop;j++){
                    try {
                      kkSocket = new Socket();
                      kkSocket.connect(sAdress, socketTimeout);
                      kkSocket.close();
                      Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      System.out.println(e);        
                    }
                    System.out.print("!");
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        String host = args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int socketTimeout = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        int loop = 100000;
        int pingLoop = 100;

        System.out.println("Begin ping. . .");
        connectAndPing(host, port, loop, pingLoop, socketTimeout);
        System.out.println("End ping. . .");
    }
}
```

It gave me result like (don't bother the mark, its just my comment)
[image]

Then i tried to ping using UNIX ping tools, and get

[image]

This is the remote machine info:

**SunOS msgbkrpapp18 5.10 Generic_138888-03 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5120

java version "1.6.0_26"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)

Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)**

Why do i get different result? which one is more valid?

Port 8000 is being used by my messaging apps, which accepting connection from external IP, my client complained that the apps is down sometimes, he read the system health by using the above java program.

If i checked in apps side, no abnormal condition met, even the threadpool for connection didn't even meet the max value.

Any suggestion??
Thank you

Comment: But the above code cannot run, since variable `j` is local to the second `for` loop. But the code is using it, outside it's scope, in `int mark = i * j + 100`. Are you sure, this is the right compilable example :-)

Comment: You are right, i have edited my post :),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days, we managed to find the culprit, it turn out, the somaxconn attributes in OS level, still in default value (128), considering our massive burst, we suggest client to configure the number into 1000;

Now, the amount of refused connection dropped 98.15%, for example, we could get almost 400 times refused connections in 1 day, now, it could drop to 6 - 9 per days.

While we are still working to give optimal tuning configuration, i would like to say thanks you to all of you for giving me some suggestions :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your code:

```
int socketTimeout = 1000;
...
kkSocket.connect(sAdress, socketTimeout);
```

The other side didn't respond in 1 second, so you get a SocketTimeoutException. Try to increase the timeout. Also have code to handle the exception - like increasing a counter for unaswered pings.

Comment: While this is true, i want to know the culprit behind this.:)

Comment: Well ping uses the ICMP Protocol not TCP. 
You are trying to connect to TCP port 8000. Maybe there is a firewall. Or something else.

I mean - you are not simulating an ICMP ping.

Answer (score -1):

The both results are valid, the difference is that Unix ping does not need to connect to specific port of the server. And it looks that your app simply does not send any response within the given timeout.

Comment: No, it looks like the server firewall is dropping the connect request.

Comment: How can you be sure about that? Especially being given such a short timeout.

Comment: A connect timeout means that the peer TCP hasn't responded. It has nothing to do with the application whatsoever.

Comment: We haven't checked from the networking side, because my client insist that the problem lies with my apps, and won't let us check the network if we can't give them proper proof..

And yes, the timeout is short, in fact they gave us 0.01sec timeout (from accepting message, decode it and send response back, pretty crazy i think..but we made it) in actual production..this is just a simple script though :), zero point time is valuable in messaing apps :D

Comment: Does your app respond successfully to the request from other hosts/networks at the same time? If yes, most probably firewall/antiviral software is concerned, as it was mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, it was designed to accept connection from other hosts. What kind of strong proof that i could make and give it as a strong admittance that it has nothing to do with the apps?

Comment: You can launch your client program on 2 distinct hosts simultaneously and check the result. If 100% of requests from host (1) are processed correctly and 100% of connections from host (2) are dropped, it would be a strong proof to check firewall/antivirus. Surely if the both hosts have no network problems (pings are OK).